# Import Definition - File not found (automation studio)

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-import

I want to import a csv file by using the automation studio.
the csv looks like that: `WERBEKO-2019_10_15`

1. Starting source: File drop (use filename Pattern "Begins with" - "WERBEKO-"
2. Import Definition: File Naming Pattern "%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%"

Error Message:

> Import failed: File WERBEKO-2019_10_15.csv.filepart not found

It works When I´m using File Naming Pattern `WERBEKO-2019_10_15` but the date will change every day.

What am I doing wrong in step 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
WERBEKO-%%Year%%_%%Month%%_%%Day%%.csv
```

Bare in mind, that each day it will only import the file with that day's date.

Read about Import wildcards on Adam's blog: https://sprignaturemoves.com/import-wildcards/